# AJAX loaded PartialView in ASP.NET MVC - script runs more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have some partial views, all of which have some similar classes (.update, .save, .cancel) but their purpose is different. On each page I write a script to work with the classes and use ajax to load the PartialView.

Everything is working except when I click the button to reload the page, the script in this page runs twice, click again and the script runs 3 time.

```
$('#gridcontainer').load("/webdata/bank", {}, function () {
    alert('Load page'); // alert run 1 time when page load, it normal
    $('body').on('click', '.save', function () { // this function run n time when i load page n time.
          var c = confirm('Do you want save?')
          if (c) {
               $(this).val('Edit').removeClass('save').addClass('update');
               var v = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
               v.eq(1).find('span').removeClass('hide');
               v.eq(1).find('input').attr('type', 'hidden');
               v.eq(2).find('input.cancel').attr('type', 'hidden');

               var id = $(this).data('id');
               // more code
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML for your main page and your partial views.

Comment: issue seems obvious, you are loading the same script each time you load content and compounding event handlers as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Remove any previous attached events when reloading , Use Jquery OFF

```
$('#gridcontainer').load("/webdata/bank", {}, function () {
    alert('Load page'); // alert run 1 time when page load, it normal
    $('body').off( "click", ".save").on('click', '.save', function () { // this function run n time when i load page n time.
          var c = confirm('Do you want save?')
          if (c) {
               $(this).val('Edit').removeClass('save').addClass('update');
               var v = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
               v.eq(1).find('span').removeClass('hide');
               v.eq(1).find('input').attr('type', 'hidden');
               v.eq(2).find('input.cancel').attr('type', 'hidden');

               var id = $(this).data('id');
               // more code
          }
     });
}
```